# How to return to my main program from an imported function in python?

Tags: python, function

I'm trying to go back to my main program from an imported function.
My situation is something like this:

```
main program
     ||
     \/
imported function
     ||
     \/
imported function (2)
```

now I want to go back from the second imported function to the main program.

```
main program  <=========\\
     ||                 ||
     \/                 ||
imported function       ||
     ||                 ||
     \/                 ||
imported function (2) ==//
```

my program looks like this:

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame import*
def main():
    while True:
        events = pygame.event.get()
        for event in events:
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                import function
```

my function looks like this:

```
print('something')
#do stuff
import function2
```

my second function is almost the same:

```
print('something')
#do stuff
'''
now I want to go back to the main program
'''
```

Comment: Execution of your main program will continue after calling a function from a module (if that function does not `sys.exit`). Or do you just want a `while True` loop around everything? You have to clarify what you mean.

Comment: What kind of program are you writing? I see this sort of code structure in a lot of amateur text adventures, and it's usually a bad idea because the whole thing crashes after the user navigates 999 rooms and Python hits its maximum recursion depth.

Comment: Why do you want to return *directly* from "imported function 2" to "main program"? Can you give an example of what these functions are? Usually, if you want a return like that, it's a sign that you've picked a bad way to structure your program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you shouldn't need to do anything extra--when you call a function from an external module, you will resume execution.  Think of it like this--there's an implicit `return` at the end of every function.  Where's it returning to?  The scope of whatever called it.  Here's some code to demonstrate what I mean:

```
import sys;

sys.stdout.write('This calls a function in the system module, leaving your main program.')
print('And its back')
```

Output:

> This calls a function in the system module, leaving your main program.
>
> And its back

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that u mean your are calling a function in your main program that is from your imported code, the subroutine will carry out and then your code in the main program will continue running for example if i import the time libary then call a function for example,

```
var = datetime.datetime.today().weekday()
```

That will return an integer that will represent the day of the week and then the code after that in the main program where i have called the time subroutine will carry on running. To get more imported functions just call them(first time answering a question so sorry in advance).